# Ruby: How to check whether a string isn't blank?

Tags: ruby, string

In my app I want to prevent a variable from being blank — e.g., a user’s name should be something other than spaces and other whitespace. It will work like this:

```rb
foobar = gets.strip
arr = []
if # the string in the variable 'foobar' isn't blank
    arr.push(foobar)
end
```

Rails adds `blank?` method to class `String`, so that `"".blank?`, `"    ".blank?`, and `nil.blank?` are all `true`. Ruby has similar `empty?` method, but it differs from `blank?`, as we can see in the example below (this won’t work in plain `irb`):

```rb
>> "      ".empty?
=> false
>> "      ".blank?
=> true
```

We see that a string of spaces is not empty, but it is blank.

Your solutions?

P.S. I gonna do this in pure Ruby, not in Rails.

Comment: Do you need something like `if "  " =~ /\A\s*\z/`?

Comment: I need any checking facility. It can be method, statement, regex.

Comment: Ursus posted the same regex variation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something exactly like rails you could require [activesupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport). Or, if something simpler can go, you could do

```
class String
  BLANK_RE = /\A[[:space:]]*\z/

  def blank?
    BLANK_RE.match?(self)
  end
end
```

The regex is taken from rails.

Comment: As a note the ActiveSupport version also returns `true` for empty arrays, empty hashes and `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Better open the predefined `String` class and implement that method

```
class String
  def blank?
    if strip.empty?
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

and also NilClass

```
class NilClass
  def blank?
    return true
  end
end
```

Now you can use the blank? function in your code.

Comment: This results in `blank?` returning `nil` for a  sting of one or more spaces.

Comment: @CarySwoveland  Yes I made a mistake, Now I have called 'strip' method. `self.strip.empty?`, It works find now.

Comment: Adding `.self` makes no difference as `self` is implied when omitted.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's the great information for me, I am not aware of this, Thank you very much.  Updated the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Gopal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40060156/4477480):

I would also use String.strip before checking on empty.

```
class String
    def blank? { self.strip.empty? }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply use ActiveRecord validation for that specific column (If we're discussing validation for model):

```
validates :name, presence: true
```

in the model- user.rb file.

The answers above are great, in case you wish to override/change the String class.
but let's look at the specifications for these cases:

`.empty?` for STRING: Returns true if str has a length of zero.

`.blank?` for an OBJECT: An object is blank if it's false, **empty**, or a whitespace string. For example, false, '', ' ', nil, [], and {} are all blank.

written in the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/).